# How can I calculate the argument of amplification factor?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

For example, I have an amplification factor of upwind scheme for hyperbolic conservation law, $$\lambda(k)=1-\nu(1-e^{-ik{\triangle}x})$$magnitude of which is
$$|\lambda|^2=1-4\nu(1-\nu)\sin^2\frac{1}{2}k{\triangle}x$$
I want to derive the argument of this amplification factor which is
$$\arg\lambda=-\tan^{-1}\left[\frac{\nu\sin k{\triangle}x}{(1-\nu)+\nu\cos k{\triangle}x}\right].$$
My text book(Numerical Solution of Partial Differential Equation : An introduction by Motron and Mayers) just gives this without explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

$$\lambda(k) = 1 - \nu (1 - e^{-ik \Delta x}) = 1 - \nu[1 - (\cos(k \Delta x) - i \sin(k \Delta x))]$$
$$ \lambda(k) = (1 - \nu  + \nu \cos(k \Delta x)) + i \nu \sin(k \Delta x)) $$

Therefore

$$\tan(\arg [\lambda(k)]) = \frac{\nu \sin(k \Delta x)}{1 - \nu  + \nu \cos(k \Delta x)}$$